# using predict.lm to generate fitted values for model terms when the model includes factors or polynomials

Tags: r

I would like to use `predict.lm` to generate fitted values for the predictors in a model.  In other words, I want to multiply the coefficient estimates in an `lm` object by the values in a new data frame with *n* rows.  The result is a matrix with *n* rows in which each value has been multiplied by its corresponding coefficient.

This is easy to do when the new data frame has a column for each of the coefficient estimates in the `lm` object.  For example:

```
y       <- rnorm(6) 
x1      <- rnorm(6)
x2      <- rnorm(6) 
modEasy <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2)
dfEasy  <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(6), x2 = rnorm(6))
predict(modEasy, newdata = dfEasy, type = "terms")
```

But it is tricky to generate fitted values when the model includes a factor variable or a polynomial.  In these cases, the new data frame has fewer than *k* columns.  For example:

```
y       <- rnorm(6) 
x1      <- rnorm(6)
x2      <- factor(rep(letters[1:3], 2))
modHard <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2)
dfHard  <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(6), x2 = factor(rep(letters[1:3], each=2)))
predict(modHard, newdata = dfHard, type = "terms")
```

In this case, `modHard$coefficients` contains estimates for `x1` and for each factor level of `x2`, just as it should.  But `dfHard` has only two columns: one for `x1` and one for `x2`.  As a result, `predict` returns a matrix with only two columns: one for `x1` and the other for `x2`.

In this situation, I want predict to return a matrix with columns for `x1` and for each level of `x2`.  I can produce that matrix with this code:

```
mf <- model.frame(formula(modHard), dfHard)
mm <- model.matrix(formula(modHard), mf)
t(modHard$coefficients * t(mm))
```

But is there a simpler way?

Comment: Shouldn't it be like: predict(modHard , data = dfHard, type = "terms") ?

Comment: @Stat -- yes, thank you.  I revised the examples.